# Will the expression $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{i^{2}}{n^{2}}}$ converge as n approches infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have the following expression:

$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}$$

I am not quite sure whether it will converge or diverge. Can somebody tell me how to figure it out?

Comment: Hint: Compare it to the Riemann integral of the function $f(x) =x^2$ over $[0,1]$. Alternatively, just use the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$.

Comment: There are many ways. One way is to recall that $\sum_1^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align} & \lim_{n \to\infty}\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}
\\ & =\lim_{n \to\infty}\ \frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2}\\ & =\lim_{n \to\infty}\ \frac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\ & =\lim_{n \to\infty}\ \frac{1}{6}\cdot (1+\frac{1}{n})(2n+1)\\ & =\frac{1}{6}\cdot (1+ 0)\cdot \infty\\ & = \infty \end{align}$$

The sequence clearly diverges.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Related: Can we substitute this "sum of squares" formula anywhere we see $i^2$. For example: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + i^2}}}$. Can we substitute this formula for $i^2$ in this expression?

Comment: No. you cannot put it there. You can only use it where you have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2}$.

Comment: How can we test this series then? As n approches infinity?

Comment: Well that should be another question. Still let me tell you that you have to take $\frac{1}{n}$ common from the expression and then use riemann sum.

Comment: @Anonymous Or if you know it already, use the comparison test.

Answer (score 3):

No. It diverges.

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}
=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2
$
and
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2
=\frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1)
\approx \frac13 n^3
$,
so
$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}
\approx \frac13 n
$.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can consider
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac {i}{n}\right)^2=\int_0^1x^2\mathrm dx=\frac13$$
Then easy to get the original limit is $\infty$.